# I cooked dinner for me myself - is that right to say that?

Tags: reflexive-pronouns

It seems like that into the sentence

> I cooked the dinner for me myself

I need to insert another "myself" because the actor and the receiver of the action is the same person (me).

But in such a case the sentence becomes weird

> I cooked the dinner for myself myself

Is it right to say it that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Myself comes in two forms:

Reflexive, where it is necessary for the meaning of the sentence: I like myself.

Intensive, where it is added for emphasis: I, myself, did the chores.

Here you are attempting to use it in both its forms. I suggest you remove the intensive myself and keep only the reflexive form: I cooked inner for myself.

The other myself is inferred.

Comment: @xenn-33 Alternatively, you could write: *I cooked my dinner myself*.